# Object array implemenation in MATLAB OOP

Tags: matlab, oop

Suppose that we have this class in MATLAB R2014b :

```
classdef Pre

properties
    Value
end

methods
    function obj = Pre(F)

        if nargin ~= 0
            m = size(F,1);
            n = size(F,2);
            obj(m,n) = Pre;

            for i = 1:m
                for j = 1:n
                    obj(i,j).Value = F(i,j);
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
end
```

**1)** If we erase `if nargin~=0` from this code we have this error :

```
Error using Pre (line 13)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in Pre (line 15)
                obj(m,n) = Pre;
```

Why? I think this is only checking for number of input arguments !

**2)** what is `obj(m,n) = Pre;`? what this line is doing in this code? This is for pre-allocating but how this line can do that?

*I checked this class with this syntax: `az = Pre([2 3 5;5 3 0])`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** In the line `obj(m,n) = Pre;` you call `Pre` without any input argument, so the variable `F` doesn't exist in that function call. It would therefore fail to do `size(F,1)` etc. MATLAB prevents this by throwing the error `not enough input arguments`. As long as you want the possibility to call `Pre` with or without input arguments, you need to check if an argument exists or not.

**2)** This does a pre-allocation. By creating an empty `Pre` at the location `(m,n)` of `obj`, MATLAB will initialize `obj` as matrix of type `Pre` and size `m`x`n`. (You can verify this for normal variables by typing `a(2,2) = 0` in the MATLAB console - it will return a 2-by-2 matrix of zeros).